# Android : Search button of Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I've tried to implement the action bar with a search field, based on the official android tuto (http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)

Here is my files :

Manifest file:

```
  <application
...
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

 <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

   <activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

...

</application>
```

(meta-data are present)

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);

    //Searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();    //MenuItemCompat.
    searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

action_bar_menu.xml :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>
```

res/xml/searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="my hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Action bar and its search button are displayed. I can input data but when clicking on the search button (virtual keyboard), nothing appends.

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_sky_reader_android, menu);

    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    setupSearchView(mSearchView);
    return true;

}


private void setupSearchView(final MenuItem searchItem) {

    searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW );
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply. It works with "setOnQueryListener" but I would like to use the "android.intent.action.SEARCH".

Answer (score 1):

The label on the searchable should be the same thar the one of the activity, try this

in the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_search"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the searchable

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="my hint"
    android:label="@string/app_search" />
```

Hope it works